# How to backup database with 20 rows in each table-mysql

Tags: mysql, backup

I want to backup a mySQL Server database with all the objects along with data but data in all the tables should be limited that is 20 rows for each table.

Comment: Tricky if you have any foreign keys and wish to keep those intact- if you do consider writing to staging db and back that up.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but maybe `mysqldump ... --where '1=1 order by limit 20'`

Comment: skip the `order by` in the above.